# Check if Graph is Connected Upon Removal of Vertices

Tags: search, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I would appreciate advice/algorithms for the following problem:

Consider a graph with V vertices connected by E edges (V, E <= 10^5). When a vertex is removed, all the edges connected to that vertex are removed. The vertices are labeled 1, 2, ..., V.

Input is given on E lines, and on each line there are two space-separated vertex numbers representing an edge between those two vertices. The next V lines are a permutation of 1, 2, ..., V, representing the order in which the vertices are removed. Output V lines stating if the graph is connected (i.e. there is a sequence of paths between every pair of vertices) at each step. V and E are known and are given as space-separated integers on the first line of input.

For example, consider the following example input (edges are undirected):

5 5

1 2

3 1

2 3

2 4

5 4

3

4

1

2

5

The first line indicates that there are 5 vertices and 5 edges. The next 5 lines describe the edges (which are undirected, i.e. an edge from 1 to 2 can also be taken from 2 to 1). The 5 lines after that give the order in which the vertices are removed.

For this example, we would get the output as follows:

When vertex 3 is removed, the graph is connected, since we can go from any of 1, 2, 4, 5 to any other of 1, 2, 4, 5. When vertex 4 is removed, the graph is disconnected because there are no connections out of vertex 5. When vertex 1 is removed the same problem exists. When vertex 2 is removed only 5 is left, so the graph is connected. When all vertices are removed the graph is connected.

I tried a naive recursive approach as follows to check if it is possible to go from a start vertex to an end vertex:

```
void dfs(int start, int curr, int end):
    if (curr == 0): // start condition, i.e. curr not yet initialized
        curr = start
    if (curr == end):
        return true
    else:
        for (int v : edges[curr]):
            dfs(start, v, end)
    return false
```

Checking at each step if it is possible to travel from all vertices A to all other vertices B using the above algorithm is far too slow (O(V^2 * E^V), algorithm should be ideally O(V log V), or maybe O(V^2) to run in about one second).

Answer (score 0):

For each step store number of partition graph has. For initial graph it is done by doing full traversal (DFS or BFS) from initial vertex, than repeat traversal from vertex that is not yet covered. If number of partitions is <= 1, than graph is connected.

If removed vertex has degree 0, than number of partition is decreased by one.

If removed vertex has degree 1, than number of partitions stays the same.

If removed vertex has degree larger than 1, than number of partitions can be increased by max degree-1. That is checked by similar traversing from neighbours of removed vertex. Start from initial neighbour and find all neighours that are connected to it. Repeat traversing from not visited neigbour.

Comment: In the case where the degree of the removed vertex is greater than 1, can you go into more detail on how to find the change in number of partitions, perhaps providing pseudocode? I don't quite understand how the complexity of this solution has a smaller upper bound than E^V for the DFS.

Comment: Traverse all nodes connected to one neighbor. If all other neighbors are visited, than removing vertex didn't split graph. If some neighbors were not visited than increase number of partitions by 1 and repeat process of traversing starting from some not visited neigbor. Note that if only one neighbor is left unvisited, there is no need to make that last traversing (starting from it.)